# How to make a list and class work together?

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to create a list in python as objects in a class. This sample code (that does not work) is trying to create a list with 2 values then print of the content of the list

I have tried different combinations including a separate class for just the list without success

```
class Fav_fruits:

    def __init__(self):
        self.person_all = []

    def add_person(self, name,age,fruit):
        self.person_all.append(name,age,fruit)

    def print_person(self):
        for table in self.person_all:
            print(table.name,table,age,table.fruit)


fruits1 = Fav_fruits()
name = "Smith"
age = 21
fruit = "apple"
fruits1.add_person(name,age,fruit)


name = "Jones"
age = 22
fruit = "pear"
fruits1.add_person(name,age,fruit)

fruits1.print_person()
```

I would like to get a printout of the contents of the list, such as
Smith 21 apple
Jones 22 pear

in later code I want to be able to change ask Smith if he has changed his favorite fruit and update it

Answer (score 0):

i did the best with the information i had but i think this is what you want

```
class Fav_fruits:

    def __init__(self):
        self.person_all = []

    def add_person(self, name,age,fruit):
        self.person_all.append([name, age, fruit])

    def print_person(self):
        for table in self.person_all:
            print(table)
        print("\n")

fruits1 = Fav_fruits()
name = "Smith"
age = 21
fruit = "apple"
fruits1.add_person(name,age,fruit)


name = "Jones"
age = 22
fruit = "pear"
fruits1.add_person(name,age,fruit)

fruits1.print_person()
```

All i changed is when you add a prson you add a list of there properteis and the output is

```
['Smith', 21, 'apple']
['Jones', 22, 'pear']
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the other answer, only difference is the formatting of the output as a string instead of a list.

```
class Fav_fruits:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person_all = []

    def add_person(self, name,age,fruit):
        self.person_all.append([name,age,fruit])

    def print_person(self):
        for table in self.person_all:
            print("{0}: {1} - {2}".format(*table))
```

With your inputs, the result is

```
Smith: 21 - apple
Jones: 22 - pear
```

You can leave out the punctuation if you wish to make it more like your desired output. I added it to illustrate the capability.

One issue with both solutions is your 'later code'. Finding Smith would mean doing a search one item at a time. e..g

```
def new_fruit(self, person, fruit):
   for p in self.person_all:
       if person = p[0]:
           p[2] = fruit
           break
```

So it might be better to change your class to store the name as a dictionary key instead of a list, depending on how big you expect it to grow and what other potential operations (other than add, and fruit replacement) that you may be contemplating. Dictionary key lookups are much faster than searching through long ists.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reports

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

It means that the `append` method only accepts one argument, but you give it three, which is name, age, and fruit

To add a new member to a list, you can aggregate your data into a `tuple`

```
class Fav_fruits:

    def __init__(self):
        self.person_all = []

    # aggregate data into a tuple
    def add_person(self, name, age, fruit):
        person = (name, age, fruit)
        self.person_all.append(person)

    # use index to retrieve your data    
    def print_person(self):
        for person in self.person_all:
            print(person[0], person[1], person[2])


fruits1 = Fav_fruits()

name = "Smith"
age = 21
fruit = "apple"
fruits1.add_person(name, age, fruit)

name = "Jones"
age = 22
fruit = "pear"
fruits1.add_person(name, age, fruit)

fruits1.print_person()
```

Then you will get

```
Smith 21 apple
Jones 22 pear
```

Or you can try

- Build another Person class for your script
- Use [namedtuple](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/namedtuple.html) to organize your data.